# Bank statement requirements for student visa in Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, student-visas, visa-sponsors

I am a Chinese student who is going to study in Amsterdam in September. I am likely to travel from the UK, where I am currently studying.

On the website, where it asks for evidence of financial support, it mentions requiring a number of things on my sponsor's bank statement, and ends in "email and/or website" (of the bank). I cannot get a bank statement with this - it seems like quite an odd request, I have asked some friends and most of their statements do not have either of these things on it. I am wondering if anyone has any experience with this - are they strict with this or will it be okay if I submit a bank statement without this?